# Form Text Field to ONLY accept numbers and whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, whitespace, textfield

I have a basic enquiry form on my website and I want one of the fields to ONLY accept numbers and keyboard spaces (whitespace).

Currently, the phone number field only accepts numbers using:

```
if(isNaN(form.phone.value)) 
{
alert('Due to SPAM this field will only accept numbers');
form.phone.focus();
return false;
}
```

When I test the form and use a keyboard space the error message is displayed. I need this field to accept numbers and whitespace. I assume people will use spaces when entering their full telephone number including country/area codes.

Comment: you need to use a regex to handle the whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks, Can you tell me how I can incorporate a regex to handle whitespaces in the code I supplied please? I am a Javascript novice! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this

```js
'use strict';

function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
  if (typeof elem === 'string') {
    elem = document.getElementById(elem);
  }

  function listenHandler(e) {
    var ret = fn.apply(null, arguments);
    if (ret === false) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    return ret;
  }

  function attachHandler() {
    window.event.target = window.event.srcElement;
    var ret = fn.call(elem, window.event);
    if (ret === false) {
      window.event.returnValue = false;
      window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    }

    return ret;
  }

  if (elem.addEventListener) {
    elem.addEventListener(event, listenHandler, false);
  } else {
    elem.attachEvent('on' + event, attachHandler);
  }
}

var keys = ' 0123456789';

function verify(e) {
  var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.charCode);
  return keys.indexOf(key) !== -1;
}

addEvent('test', 'keypress', verify);
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" />
```

Update: As everything supports [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) these days, you don't need all the additional boilerplate. And the above could be written like.

```js
'use strict';

const element = document.getElementById('test');
const keys = ' 0123456789';
element.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  if (keys.includes(e.key) === false) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" />
```

Info:

[keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)

[KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Key_names_and_Char_values)

[Event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

[Event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 0):

Use html5 input type="tel" attribute (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp).